# How to programmatically expand/collapse Vertical UIViews build with constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, autolayout

i'm not very familiar with autolay-out and constraints.
I have build a view with 7 subviews which are build with constraints to fit landscape and portait mode. Everything is fine (see picture).

Here under a sample code used for the 6th subview.
The width constraint has mediumPriority and the others (left, top, bottom) have highPriority.

```
    6View = UIView()
    mainScrollView.addSubview(6View)
    6View.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 120/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1.0)
    6View.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // constraints
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: 6View, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: kMainMargin)
    topConstraint.priority = highContraintPriority
    mainScrollView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: 6View, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: day5View, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: kMainMargin)
    leftConstraint.priority = highContraintPriority
    mainScrollView.addConstraint(leftConstraint)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: 6View, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: kMainMargin)
    bottomConstraint.priority = highContraintPriority
    mainScrollView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: 6View, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mainScrollView, attribute: .width, multiplier: (1/7), constant: -1)
    widthConstraint.priority = mediumContraintPriority
    mainScrollView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```

Now i'd like when i touch any of the 7 views to see the touched view to expand (double size) and the other 6 views to collapse.

How would you achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a reference to the width constraint for every view and when clicked do

```
widthConstraint.constant = // expanded value
```

and set  this for all the other views

```
otherwidthConstraint.constant = 0
```

then call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

You may also put all these constraints inside an array ( `var arrOfAllWidths = [NSLayoutConstraint]()`) and do this

```
arrOfAllWidths.forEach { $0.constant = 0 }
```

then get the index of the clicked view say it's view 0

```
arrOfAllWidths[0].constant = // expanded value
```

Also no need for the priorities , and don't forget to set this when give constraints to a view programmatically

```
view6.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```